# Ошибка "LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный символ..." в Visual Studio 2019 при установки библиотеки intel-mkl

Tags: c++, библиотеки, visual-studio-2019, lnk2019

У меня следующая проблема. Есть необходимость установить библиотеку mkl(оттуда нужны преимущественно lapack и blas для работы с матрицами и линейной алгеброй). На самом деле не принципиально, чтобы все это работало в Visual Studio, если подскажете, где и как можно еще, буду благодарен.

Собственно, я скачал отсюда библиотеку: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-mkl-on-windows и, вроде как, проделал все необходимые действия по ее установке: добавил в папку проекта dll файлы; в свойствах проекта, вкладка "C/C++ -> общие -> дополнительные каталоги включаемых файлов" добавил папку include из установленной библиотеки; в свойствах проекта, вкладка "Компоновщик -> общие -> дополнительные каталоги библиотек" добавил папку lib и в "Компоновщик -> ввод -> дополнительные зависимости" прописал 2 файла .lib, которые были в установленном архиве.

Следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mkl.h>

int main()
{
    char transa = 'N';
    char transb = 'N';
    int n = 2;
    double alpha = 1.0;
    const double mat[4] = { 1, 2, 3, 2 };
    const double mat2[4] = { 2, 2, 2, 2 };
    double res[4] = {};
    DGEMM(&transa, &transb, &n, &n, &n, &alpha, mat, &n, mat2, &n, &alpha, res, &n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

выдаёт ошибку LNK2019: неразрешенный внешний символ _DGEMM в функциях _main.
В общем подскажите, пожалуйста, что я сделал не так. Если есть вариант сделать это где-то не в VS, тоже устраивает, т.к. функционал библиотек нужен в ближайшее время.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте включать `mkl_cblas.h` и использовать `cblas_dgemm`.

Comment: Попробовал, то же самое выдает

Comment: Оно не может выдавать то же самое, так как после этих изменений символ `_DGEMM` больше не будет использоваться.

Comment: Я имею ввиду то же самое, но с другим названием функции: "LNK2019: неразрешенный внешний символ _cblas_dgemm в функциях _main"

Comment: ¿А платформа точно x64? _ не должно там появляться

Comment: Вот с платформами я не уверен. Можете, пожалуйста, про это подробнее написать, или сказать, что и где почитать. В visual studio сверху, рядом с debug у меня стоит x86, потому что при x64 вылетает куча ошибок, по типу "идентификатор CBLAS_LAYOUT не определен" и "не удается открыть источник файл mkl_cblas.h".  Винда у меня x64, при установке архива ничего нигде про x64 или x86 не было написано, поэтому в visual studio ничего связанного с этим не настраивал.

Comment: А ну тогда ясно, там должно быть x64 (в архиве бинари x64) и в  свойствах проекта надо было задавать их для x64 (там тоже в верху это переключается)

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, подробнее расписать. Вот я скачал архив, разархивировал, в нем есть папка include и lib. Создал новый проект. Выше, в формулировке вопроса я описал свои действия, что делал в свойствах проекта. Что нужно было делать, чтобы все работало конкретно для x64(потому что я просто добавлял пути, где находятся эти папки и не понимаю, где там выбирать для x64/x86)? потому что, как я упомянул ранее, при выборе сверху возле debug x64 вылетает много ошибок. Я понимаю, что сильно туплю :( поэтому нужен как можно более подробный ответ.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Платформа и конфигурация указываются в окне свойствах проекта вверху. Собственно эти свойства задаются для выбранной комбинации платформы и конфигурации.